# Doctrine Entity values are all null except for id

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to fetch an Object from the database with the repository method `findOneBy` (id).

Basically, the line looks like this:

```
public function findAssignedTickets(User $user)
{
    $userId = $user->getId();
    $ticketMapping = new ResultSetMapping;
    $ticketMapping->addEntityResult(Ticket::class, 't');
    $ticketMapping->addFieldResult('t', 'id', 'id');

    // Postgresql Native query, select all tickets where participants array includes the userId
    $query = "SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT id, array_agg(e::text::int) arr
        FROM ticket, json_array_elements(participants) e
        GROUP BY 1
        ) s
    WHERE 
        $userId = ANY(arr);
    ";
    $results = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($query, $ticketMapping)->getResult();

    $results = array_map(function($item) {
        return $item->getId();
    }, $results); // Transform to array in integers

    dump($results); // array:2 [0 => 83, 1 => 84] -> It's correct

    $tickets = [];

    foreach ($results as $ticketId) {
        dump($this->findOneById($ticketId));
        // $ticket = $this->findOneById($ticketId);
        // $tickets[] = [
        //     'identifier' => $ticket->getIdentifier(),
        //     'title' => $ticket->getTitle(),
        //     'author' => $ticket->getAuthor()->getUsername(),
        //     'status' => $ticket->getStatus(),
        //     'created' => $ticket->getCreatedAt()->format('c'),
        //     'updated' => $ticket->getUpdatedAt()->format('c'),
        // ]; // Ticket formatting to send in json
    }

    return $tickets;
}
```

which will output :
[image: Symfony dump]

And I'm sure that the received id matches a row in the database, and that the database contains data, and all fields belong directly to the entity, except for author which represents a ManyToOne and I heard about the lazy displaying of Doctrine, but it shouldn't happen on other fields.

Why can't I retrieve data from the Object even with getters, and why are all the values set to null **Except** for id ?

EDIT : I was wondering if that had a connexion to the ResultSetMapping I used to fetch the tickets IDs in a totally separate request earlier, and when I added a `addFieldResult('t', 'title', 'title');` it did the work, but not on the other fields, another mystery.

Comment: Strange that your ticket entity seems to have a property called em.  Might have expected it in a TicketProxy but not a regular Ticket.  Almost seems like some sort of active record implementation.  I'm a bit suspicious of the claim that the posted code is "basically" like your actual code.  I suspect you have more going on.  Try a basic: $ticket=$ticketRepository->find(84); dump($ticket); and work your way from there.

Comment: I tried your method, and it gives me the same. This is indeed really weird.

Comment: Is this a basic app or do you have a bundle of third party stuff involved.  It is possible to add some unexpected functionality though I can't really think of what sort of functionality would be causing this.  Maybe triple check that the app is connecting to the database you think it is.  I have on occasion looked in one database while my app was manipulating another one.

Comment: I wondered if somehow it was related to the fact that the resultSetMapping I used on a totally separate request had an impact on the result. It was weird that the column I was mapping the result onto was id. So I checked with title, and it works on the title column. But now the mystery is why? I will update my post so you have the full context.

Comment: And to answer your question, this is a really basic app where the only third party bundle I'm using is Nelmio_cors to handle CORS request. this is my first Symfony project and the goal of this one is to understand how it works witch Doctrine, but here I am, stuck

Comment: It's possible that your first query is storing your tickets in it's internal UnitOfWork storage.  You could confirm by commenting out the query and just building a fake results array.  It is a bit puzzling why you are doing a mapping in the first place when all you need is the ticket id.

Comment: Indeed, by removing the first query it seems to work. I wanted to make a "softer and more readable" request based on the array of ticket ids I retrieved, but in terms of performance this is clearly not the best. I will build a ManyToMany relation instead and make normal request, thanks for figuring out what the problem was. I don't think posting a solution as it has no true solution except not doing what I did, but maybe it is a unexpected bug of Doctrine for doing unexpected things (is it a bug then ?)

Comment: Not a bug but a feature.  Doctrine caches all objects retrieved from the database and will re-use them if they are queried a second time.  Might be possible to clear the unit of work but that will almost certainly cause it's own set of problems.  You could drop down to pure sql if you wanted but setting a relation seems a better idea.